# Can any New Zealand-based NFPs share their CiviCRM experiences?

Tags: evaluating-civicrm

In the absence of a "users" mailing list where I would normally post this, I'm based in New Zealand, and I'm looking for New Zealand-based end-users or administrators of CiviCRM happy to share some experiences off-list about how well (or not) it's working. I am absolutely not interested in talking to any vendors or consultants, only folks who are actually using and supporting it in house (either hosted on on-premises).

Ideally your organisation would be at the medium end of the size scale (at least in NZ terms). Any experiences at all though would be welcome appreciated.

If any folks out there are keen please let me know.

Cheers,
Dave

Comment: I can absolutely recommend a person or two to talk to in NZ - but I'm not comfortable posting their information here.  If you post on the forums with some way to reach out privately to you, and you update this question to link to the forum post, I'm happy to connect you.

Comment: Hi Jon, that would be awesome, thanks. Forum post with a private email address is here:

https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=37163.msg156889#msg156889

Answer (score 1):

there's a board on the CiviCRM forums for NZ users - you might get a better dialogue by posting this question there: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?board=78.0 . StackExchange is better for a straight Q&A format.

There are a number of CiviCRM agencies who may be able to point you to testimonials of their clients. You can search for CiviCRM experts in your country on the CiviCRM website: https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors?country=1154&service_languages_181=All&services=All&supported_cms_s_182=All